# How can I get the Intellij debugger to treat custom scala monads the same as the standard ones?

Tags: scala, debugging, intellij-idea, monads

If I have a scala for-comprehension with lists like

```
def getList: List[A]
def doSomeStuff(a: A): List[B]

for {
  a <- getList
  x <- doSomeStuff(a)
} yield x
```

and I step through it with the debugger in Intellij, the debugger is smart enough not to step into the internal map/flatMap implementations of the List class. I can inspect the `getList` and `doSomeStuff` calls without thinking about the monad plumbing at work in the background.

However when I implement my own monads, the debugger doesn't behave the same way, it steps right in and shows all the guts of the monad implementation. While this is nice for initially debugging the monad, it makes it much harder to debug code that uses the monad. Is there a way to get the debugger to treat custom monads the same as the standard library ones so that no one is driven insane while debugging my code?

Answer (score -1):

In [this document](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/SCA/Scala+Debugger+Settings) is explained how you could exclude specific packages or classes from the debugger stepping into them. If your monad is isolated enough from code you want to debug you could add it to the exclude list.